# text box contents from multiple list box selection

Tags: javascript

I want to populate the selection from multiple list boxes to a single text box.
I've played around with it a bit but I'm still having trouble getting it to work

Many Thanks Brian

Comment: So you want to take multiple text box values and insert them into one big text box?

Comment: Brian, Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: I dont have anything so far that works! I've tried a few examples but nothing was working well.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Lee

I have done a simple example. Please check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/sAEn6iBkwmZuWq56yHVT?p=preview

Created three set of `<select>` and a `<textarea>`. On change of select, updated textarea :

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
  $("textarea").val( $("textarea").val() +' '+ $(this).find("option:selected").val() );
})
```

Comment: Your example works well, but I cant seem to implement it in my PDF which contain the various list boxes and text box.

Comment: Maybe you can explain more about the use case. Are you trying to implement this for a PDF list?